# Serilog not logging to Sentry levels different than Error

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, serilog, sentry

I want log to `sentry.io` `Information` log level using serilog.

In `appsettings.json` I made this config:

```
"Sentry": {
    "Dsn": "url",
    "MaxRequestBodySize": "Always",
    "SendDefaultPii": true,
    "IncludeActivityData": true,
    "AttachStackTrace": true,
    "Debug": true,
    "DiagnosticLevel": "Info"
  },
  "Serilog": {
    "Using": [
      "Serilog.Sinks.Console"
    ],
    "MinimumLevel": {
      "Default": "Debug",
      "Override": {
        "Microsoft": "Warning",
        "System": "Error",
        "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command": "Information"
      }
    },
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "Console",
        "Args": {
          "theme": "Serilog.Sinks.SystemConsole.Themes.SystemConsoleTheme::Literate, Serilog.Sinks.Console",
          "outputTemplate": "[{Timestamp:HH:mm:ss} {Properties} {SourceContext} [{Level}] {Message:lj}{NewLine}{Exception}"
        }
      },
      {
        "Name": "Sentry",
        "Args": {
          "theme": "Serilog.Sinks.SystemConsole.Themes.SystemConsoleTheme::Literate, Serilog.Sinks.Console",
          "outputTemplate": "[{Timestamp:HH:mm:ss} {Properties} {SourceContext} [{Level}] {Message:lj}{NewLine}{Exception}"
        }
      }
    ],
    "Enrich": [
      "FromLogContext",
      "WithMachineName",
      "WithThreadId",
      "WithHtpContextData",
      "WithExceptionDetails"
    ]
  }
```

I registered serilog and sentry into my `Program.cs` class:

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>                                                           
    Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)                                                                                      
        .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>                                                                          
        {                                                                                                                
            webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();                                                                            
            webBuilder.UseSentry();                                                                                      
        })                                                                                                               
        .UseSerilog((hostingContext, loggerConfig) => loggerConfig.ReadFrom.Configuration(hostingContext.Configuration));
```

In my class i make code like this:

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Quartz;
using Serilog;

//

private readonly ILogger _logger;

public QueuedJob(ILogger logger)
{
    _logger = logger;
}

public Task Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
{
    _logger.Information("Hello World!");
            
    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

Why from this configuration in `sentry.io` portal i see only logs that i logged as `Error` level? Why i cant log into `sentry.io` `Information` level? All levels of logs are printed to my console but only `Errors` are printed into console and `sentry.io`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, the Sentry Serilog integration only sends events for log level `Error` or higher.

For `Info` logs, the SDK keeps a ring buffer so when an error happens all related logs are included with that event.

[image: Sentry Breadcrumbs]

This can be configured though, you can send everything (`Debug` or higher for example): https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/dotnet/guides/serilog/#configuration

In fact, I use this exact setup on [NuGet Trends](https://nugettrends.com/) to capture any `Warning` or higher as event, and include any `Debug` or higher as breadcrumb:

Here's the configuration:

https://github.com/dotnet/nuget-trends/blob/dac67d1bd4707a94063b843571127eb055a4cc4f/src/NuGetTrends.Scheduler/appsettings.Production.json#L33-L34

Comment: I just moved levles to `Sentry--args` in appsettings and i get `info` level into my Sentry. Thanks